# Produciton of EM waves with differing wavelengths

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, sun

Sun is the major source of electromagnetic radiation. Then if the source is the same, how are different EM waves with differing wavelengths produced?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

Answer (score 2):

Monochromatic light is only produced if the charge motion in a source has a strictly periodic motion with a fixed period. Sun has many different charges moving aperiodically, so it produces the whole spectrum of frequencies. You can imagine it as a huge set of different sources with different frequencies.